# Include libraries in executable

Tags: linker, include, static-libraries, executable

How can I include the libraries I'm using in my C++ program (sqlite3, vector, etc.) in an executable file fully functioning I can give to my friends?

Comment: This is linker and operating system dependent. What operating system are you compiling and linking for? What compiler do you use?

Comment: I am compiling for Windows on Mingw GCC (dev-C++).